# Deploy migration files to production on pythonanywhere

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

I have a local django project which is also hosted on pythonanywhere.

I just run into a merge conflict with the migration files (which I solved). Now I a wondering; should deploy my local migration files alongside the code or have two separate set of migration files?

Comment: Why two? Where's the second one coming from? You should *only* have the local ones, which should be committed to source control and deployed along with the rest of the code.

Comment: I had two due to a mistake. I am now doing as you said (deploy my local migrations alongside the code) & everything works fine. Thanks!